# SugarCRM reports module not formatted

Tags: php, json, module, report, sugarcrm

I am using

SugarCRM Pro 6.4.4

php 5.3.0

apache 2.2.11

My problem is that clicking the Reports module would display a text-formatted response (JSON format). When clicking the Create Report would also respond the same. I was expecting the Report Wizard wherein I could choose whether my report would be in Rows and Columns, Summation or more.

Below is a part of the response sent by Sugar.

> ACLAllowedModules = ["Leads","Cases","Bugs","Prospects","Project","ProjectTask","Campaigns","CampaignLog","Releases","Contacts","Accounts","Opportunities","Notes","Calls","Emails","Meetings","Tasks","Users","Currencies","Trackers","TrackerSessions","TrackerPerfs","TrackerQueries","Documents","DocumentRevisions","EmailAddresses","Teams","Quotes","Products","ProductTypes","ProductCategories","Forecasts","Contracts","KBDocuments"]; var module_defs = new Object(); default_summary_columns = ['count'];

I tested the reports module in sugarcrm pro 6.1.6 but the result is okay.

Update:
I have fixed the problem. Turns out, sugar is calling a classname that is invalid. Corrected the classname and it is now working. By the way, the classname sugar is calling is a customized/overriden classname.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error occur as a result of a bad vardefs.php custom field definition in a custom module. In my specific instance, I was trying to make a custom field pull from a custom list of values with the following code.

Bad vardefs code:

`'customField' => array(
    ...
    'type' => 'enum',
    'function' => array(
        'name' => 'getCustomListOfValues', 
        'params' => array('foobar')
    )
    ...
),`

My issue was fixed by breaking out the function params:

`'customField' => array(
    ...
    'type' => 'enum',
    'function' => 'getCustomListOfValues',
    'function_params' => array('foobar')
    ...
),`